# How to calculate Energy readings from the raw data on an Power Meter

Tags: python, modbus, pymodbus

I'm IoT newbie and I have a project with Schneider Power Meter.
I read voltage raw data from registers using `pymodbus` but I don't know how to convert it to the correct value.

Raw data is `[24206, 17242]` from registers address `3927-3928`.

Here is my code :

```
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusSerialClient as ModbusClient

def main():
    try:
        register = int(input("Registers: "))
        modbus = ModbusClient(method='rtu', port='COM4', baudrate=9600, timeout=1, 
            parity='E', bytesize=8
        )
        modbus.connect()
        r = modbus.read_holding_registers(register, 2, unit=1)
        print(r.registers)
        modbus.close()
        return r.registers
    except AttributeError as e:
        print(e)
        return None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Out:

```
[24206, 17242]
```

[Registers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKyEF.png)

[Voltage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDvuO.png)

[Raw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBZbz.png)

Can everyone tell me how to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the conversion method from raw data to true value?

Comment: You need to decode your received raw data to `float32` or `Int32`. Please put on your code in the question with an edit. I can resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still, I'm waiting for your code, but with my guess, you will need like the following stuff:

## Reading and decoding:

```
from pymodbus.constants import Endian
from pymodbus.payload import BinaryPayloadDecoder
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusTcpClient

def validator(instance):
    if not instance.isError():
        '''.isError() implemented in pymodbus 1.4.0 and above.'''
        decoder = BinaryPayloadDecoder.fromRegisters(
            instance.registers,
            byteorder=Endian.Big, wordorder=Endian.Little
        )   
        return float(decoder.decode_32bit_float())

    else:
        # Error handling.
        print("There aren't the registers, Try again.")
        return None


client = ModbusTcpClient('X.X.X.X', port=502)
connection = client.connect()

if connection:
    request = client.read_holding_registers(3927, count=2, unit=1)
    data = validator(request)
    print(data)

    client.close()

else:
    print('Connection lost, Try again')
```

---

[**NOTE**]:

Your data either is *float32* or *float32_inverse*.

- Thus, with the *float32* you will have:

  ```
   wordorder=Endian.Big
  ```
- And with the *float32_inverse* you will have:

  ```
   wordorder=Endian.Little
  ```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I run my code in windows and it has no error, i also compare result with Modscan, it the same but i dont known how Modscan convert raw data to float(LSRF)

Comment: @Mr.Ping I don't about Modscan, But I worked with ModbusPoll app, It has all type of decoders also.

Comment: Thank you very much! It run!

Comment: @Mr.Ping So you can accept the answer if it is done :)