# Modbus Python Schneider PM5300

Tags: python, modbus, rs485, pymodbus

I'm trying to get voltage or current from PM5300 meter, but always come 32768 only.
The code:

```
from pymodbus.constants import Endian
from pymodbus.payload import BinaryPayloadDecoder
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusSerialClient as ModbusClient
import logging

FORMAT = ('%(asctime)-15s %(threadName)-15s '
          '%(levelname)-8s %(module)-15s:%(lineno)-8s %(message)s')
logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT)
log = logging.getLogger()
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

UNIT = 0x01


def run_sync_client():
    client = ModbusClient(method='rtu', port='COM15', timeout=1, baudrate=19200, parity='E', stopbits=1, bytesize=8)
    client.connect()

    request = client.read_holding_registers(address=43010, count=2, unit=UNIT)
    result = request.registers
    print(result)
    decoder = BinaryPayloadDecoder.fromRegisters(result, Endian.Little, wordorder=Endian.Big)
    #dc2 = (decoder.decode_32bit_float() + 32768 /1000)
    #print(dc2)
    print(decoder.decode_32bit_float())


    client.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_sync_client()
```

The address 3010 in register list matches to current (4 is the holding register).

The log and print with Endian.Little:

```
2020-06-16 20:11:24,349 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :115      Current transaction state - IDLE
2020-06-16 20:11:24,349 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :120      Running transaction 1
2020-06-16 20:11:24,350 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :219      SEND: 0x1 0x3 0xa8 0x2 0x0 0x2 0x45 0xab
2020-06-16 20:11:24,350 MainThread      DEBUG    sync           :75       New Transaction state 'SENDING'
2020-06-16 20:11:24,350 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :228      Changing transaction state from 'SENDING' to 'WAITING FOR REPLY'
2020-06-16 20:11:24,364 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :304      Changing transaction state from 'WAITING FOR REPLY' to 'PROCESSING REPLY'
2020-06-16 20:11:24,365 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :233      RECV: 0x1 0x3 0x4 0x80 0x0 0x80 0x0 0xb2 0x33
2020-06-16 20:11:24,365 MainThread      DEBUG    rtu_framer     :180      Getting Frame - 0x3 0x4 0x80 0x0 0x80 0x0
2020-06-16 20:11:24,365 MainThread      DEBUG    factory        :266      Factory Response[ReadHoldingRegistersResponse: 3]
2020-06-16 20:11:24,365 MainThread      DEBUG    rtu_framer     :115      Frame advanced, resetting header!!
2020-06-16 20:11:24,366 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :383      Adding transaction 1
2020-06-16 20:11:24,366 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :394      Getting transaction 1
2020-06-16 20:11:24,366 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :193      Changing transaction state from 'PROCESSING REPLY' to 'TRANSACTION_COMPLETE'
[32768, 32768]
**2020-06-16 20:11:24,366 MainThread      DEBUG    payload        :312      [32768, 32768]**
2020-06-16 20:11:24,367 MainThread      DEBUG    payload        :368      [b'\x00\x80', b'\x00\x80']
1.1755122874426309e-38
```

With Endian.Big the result: -4.591774807899561e-41

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in the register number you are trying to read. On *pymodbus* you have to indicate registers as absolute address numbers; you don't have to add 40000 to the Modbus map as you did.

Just change this line:

```
request = client.read_holding_registers(address=43010, count=2, unit=UNIT)
```

to:

```
request = client.read_holding_registers(address=3010, count=2, unit=UNIT)
```

That should give you the current average according to the [map](https://www.se.com/ww/en/faqs/FA234017/) of your meter.

I don't have access to a meter right now but if my notes are correct the endianness should be `byteorder=Endian.Big, wordorder=Endian.Little` so you might want to fiddle with that in your code too.

Reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53275427/how-to-calculate-energy-readings-from-the-raw-data-on-an-power-meter) might be worth your while, it has some code that I think targets the same family of Schneider Electric devices.

I would argue it would be better if instead of an apparently correct reading you'd get a wrong address error, which is what you should be getting in this case. I imagine they wanted to keep open the option to add more registers to the map and they kept it unbounded.

**EDIT:** As discussed in the comments below the correct register to read for the current average is 3009, so the request should be:

```
request = client.read_holding_registers(address=3009, count=2, unit=UNIT)
```

Some devices give you holding register numbers starting from 40001. For *pymodbus* and others the first holding register is number 0, so if the Modbus map of the device you should read register number 45125, for instance, you need to subtract 40001 to get the `address` for *pymodbus*:

```
address=45125-40001=5124
```

The case you are dealing with here is even more annoying: the map starts with register 1 so you need to subtract 1.

As you can see on the following screenshot:

[image: ModbusPoll screenshot]

ModbusPoll follows the same logic: by default you have to enter 0 for register 40001 (or 10 for register 40011. If you click the check box PLC addresses you will have to enter 1 to read from address 40001.

Yes, I know, confusing!

Note that the question in the link above does **not** mention the -1 offset. Some devices (like yours!) will not let you read from "the wrong" register. Such that, if you want to read current average (which is a FLOAT32 and hence occupies two registers) you need to start reading from register 3009 and read two registers (yes, the map says 3010 but keep in mind the -1 offset). If instead, you start from register 3010 you are actually trying to read the upper half part of the current average and the lower half of the next variable (current imbalance). Since you will not be able to get any useful data because you are reading two mixed up variables you get an error. Again, not the best error; it should at least give you some hint of what you are doing wrong, but alas!

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to mencionate that I had tried it... using only address=3036 (voltage register example) crashes the program: 2020-06-17 09:46:59,422 MainThread      DEBUG    transaction    :193      Changing transaction state from 'PROCESSING REPLY' to 'TRANSACTION_COMPLETE'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\160620.py", line 32, in <module>
    run_sync_client()
  File ".\160620.py", line 20, in run_sync_client
    result = request.registers
AttributeError: 'ExceptionResponse' object has no attribute 'registers'

Comment: I see... Are you sure UNIT is correct? I think you need to review the configuration on your meter. I'm pretty sure you don't need the 4xxxx offset so something else must be wrong

Comment: UNIT is a var, in the begin of the code I use UNIT = 0x01. It works because I have answer, it can be only 1 too. The 4xxxx, is the code of holding_register, like 1 if was COIN.. I don't know more where could be, I read documentation about modbus and pymodbus

Comment: As I said I don't have a meter with me now so it's not possible for me to be 100% sure. Have you tried reading from register 3009 instead of 3010. Sometimes there is -1 offset and the device will not allow you to read starting from the upper register. You can also download and check the connection with [ModScan](https://www.win-tech.com/html/demos.htm)

Comment: Yes, I tried right now with 3035 (3036 is the register of L-N Avg Voltage (110v in the test)). A curious fact is that i tried with 2 softwares: (modbus scan - that worked and give me the lecture of meter) and (Modbus Poll - that give me the same value of python: 32768 in all valid registers)

Comment: And what values did you input in ModScan? That makes sense, in Modbus Poll you enter the same register values as in pymodbus (the manual says "enter 10 for register 40011") by default but there is a click box marked "Use PLC Addresses (base 1)", have you tried that? you have to be careful with the serial port settings too

Comment: It works! You are totally correct. I should use register -1, I used 3035 again and it works, I don't know why doesn't work before when I commented here.. but it works. Thank you so much for your great help Marcos!

Comment: I'm glad it worked. I'm going to edit my answer to include your comments. Have fun with your meter.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solución with this format the PM5500 series use ieee format to float data.